# Cannot locate beanDefinitationDecorator for element

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping, spring-tool-suite

My Servlet-context.xml on property name = mapping im getting multiple annotations found at this line

```
    <beans:bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">

        <property name="mappings">
            <props>
                <props key="page.pdf">pdfController</props>
            </props>            
        </property>

</beans:bean>



<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />


</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.me.controller" />
```

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with? Which line is causing the problem?

Comment: I am getting error "multiple annotations found at this line" at  <property name="mappings"> i did used prop but still error exists.. which is Cannot locate beanDefinitationDecorator for element.

Answer (score 0):

A single property needs to be identified with the `prop` element, not `props`. Try

```
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
  <property name="mappings">
    <props>
      <prop key="page.pdf">pdfController</prop>
    </props>
  </property>
</bean>
```